# installing qt4-make on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: c, makefile, qt4, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I am running ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS on my controller. I was trying to install qt4-make using apt-get, but I am getting a message that the package is not found. I need this to make and compile a file. How can I install this ? Also, is there any alternative I can download ? I even tried sudo apt-get install libqt4-* . Still nothing happens.

Comment: may be belongs to `askubuntu`? Anyways you can always build the package from source.

Answer (score 0):

I think qt4-make is qmake, so try this:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake
```